# How do I paginate data from Firebase using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebase, pagination

As an application gets bigger, data in `Firebase` gets bigger too. I have an application in `Ruby on Rails` that stores all the data in `Firebase`. In order to show all the data I just load from url data as `JSON` and show it on views. Now it loads the data very slowly because it downloads whole `JSON`.

Is there a way to make firebase paginate all that data and optimize the load?

This is how I load the data:

```
    url = URI("******************")

    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = true
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
    request["cache-control"] = 'no-cache'
    request["postman-token"] = 'efe418a4-1dcc-335b-28c9-ba72cc2f5aa0'

    response = http.request(request)
    all_letters = JSON.parse(response.read_body)
    im = 1
    all_letters.each do |item|
        ...
    end
```

Comment: Can you provide some code samples? Like controller method where you get your data loaded and pass it to the view

Comment: @AntonTkachov added controller

Comment: I see that you have very poor experience with Rails. Such codebase is unmaintainable.... You need to provide a page parameter to load_articles and then use it in your request to firebase (not sure about exact syntax). I am not ready to go into your code to research or provide a real sample. It's too big and creepy.

Comment: Why do you use firebase in rails application? Why haven't you gone with sqlite/mysql/postgresql?

Comment: hi, how can I help you to solve this issue? I read your post but I need to dig deeper to help you

Comment: @AntonTkachov I use FireBase because all the data is being stored on Firebase, we get it from mobile applications.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio so, yes. I would like to paginate all the data by retrieving data from firebase url. Maybe by using filters and so on.

Answer (score 0):

if I had to do this I would, first easily `get` the pages from firebase with [`firebase-ruby`](https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby) gem

```
base_uri = 'https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/'

firebase = Firebase::Client.new(base_uri)

response = firebase.push("todos", { :name => 'Pick the milk', :'.priority' => 1 })
response.success? # => true
response.code # => 200
response.body # => { 'name' => "-INOQPH-aV_psbk3ZXEX" }
response.raw_body # => '{"name":"-INOQPH-aV_psbk3ZXEX"}'
```

then to show them on pages, I would install [`will_paginate`](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)

> ## [Basic will_paginate use](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate#basic-will_paginate-use)
>
> perform a paginated query:

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])
```

> or, use an explicit "per page" limit:

```
Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

> render page links in the view:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

> And that's it! You're done. You just need to add some CSS styles to make those pagination links prettier.
>   You can customize the default "per_page" value:
>
> for the Post model

```
class Post
  self.per_page = 10
end
```

> set per_page globally

```
WillPaginate.per_page = 10
```

Comment: So, I need to load firstly all data from my firebase and after show that? And it should be done whenever page gets loaded? Because it should work as realtime

Comment: @AliTlekbay how slow is it? include your server log

Comment: well its not that slow, but I expect that in the future its going to be way more slower